# Make numpy.genfromtext return comma separated tuples

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, genfromtxt

I am using 
`text = np.sort(np.genfromtxt('new1', delimiter= ' ',dtype=None,usecols=[1,2]))`

and while printing text, the result I get is space separated values.

`[(10014024, 'GAM.SW') (10014031, 'GAM.SW') (10014032, 'GAM.SW')
 (10014032, 'HAM.SW') (10014033, 'GAM.SW') (10014034, 'ZAM.SW')]`

and not

`[(10014024, 'GAM.SW'),(10014031, 'GAM.SW'),(10014032, 'GAM.SW'),
(10014032, 'HAM.SW'),(10014033, 'GAM.SW'),(10014034, 'ZAM.SW')]`

Because of this, I am getting some error in the further part of the program.How can I get the comma separated value?

Comment: That's just how numpy formats the arrays after print. Can you add the Traceback of the error completely in your question?

Comment: I have two files and I am comparing the values. <br> on comparing  (10014024, 'GAM.SW') (10014022, 'GAM.SW')`, i am getting -1

Comment: Why on earth you think this problem is related to the commas between your items?? more importantly how you're comparing them together? and why you got -1?

Comment: `text` is a 1d structured array.  How are you comparing the arrays?

Comment: Thanks guys. i got it.. the numpy nd array is of type void andso I was getting false comparisons.